# Selecting the appropriate algorithm for creating and calculating permutations of element-sharing pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, permutation, graph-algorithm

I am interested in what algorithm would have the lowest time complexity for performing the following task:

Given a list of tuples, such as [(A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D E), (A, D), (E, A), (A, C)],
find sequences such as [**A**, B, C, D, E, **A**] or [**A**, D, C, B, **A**], which **start and end** with the same letter and are being formed by joining pairs that share at least one element of the tuple. Note: (A, B) is being considered to be the same as (B, A), just like (A, C) is the same as (C, A), so it can be used to create both pair (**C**, B, A, **C**) or (**A**, B, C, **A**)

The important constraint is having a limit on the length. E.g. making sure that sequence is no longer than 7 total elements.

I've attempted to solve this problem by expanding the tree one element at the time until the max length of 7 is reached, but I am curious if there are better approaches to solving this problem. Thank you so much and looking forward to hearing your great ideas!

Comment: So when you have (A,B), then (A,B,A) is a solution? Or is there a constraint that a tuple can only be used once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Time Complexity

The (worst-case) time complexity of any algorithm for solving this problem will have a lower bound of *O(n)* where *n* is the number of edges (i.e. tuples) of the graph:

- In case you need to find *all* cycles from A to A, you cannot exclude looking a certain edge, as it might well be part of one such cycle.
- In case you need to find *any* cycle from A to A, you might be in a situation where there is only one such cycle, and in the worst-case you may find that the last edge you visit is the one closing the cycle.

So in either situation, you (may) need to look at each edge at least once.

### Algorithms

In essence there are two strategies: breadth-first or depth-first search. Both have a time complexity of *O(n)*.

The algorithm you seem to have tried with is a breadth-first search. It is the better choice when you need to find the *shortest* cycle, because then you can exit the algorithm as soon as you find a cycle (A-to-A).

A depth-first search is also a viable option, certainly when there is a limit set to the length of the cycle. In that case the *space* complexity is *O(m)*, where *m* is the maximum length of a cycle. Depending on the graph (its size, its average branching factor), this could be much cheaper than the *O(n)* space that a breadth-first search requires.

Also, a breadth-first search needs to constantly switch states, while the transitions that occur during recursion and backtracking (characteristic of a depth-first search) are often easier to deal with.

### Preparations

Whichever strategy you use, make sure to first create an efficient data structure for the graph.

The simple data structure that consists of an array of pairs (like depicted in your question) is not good enough. For achieving the optimal time complexity, you need to build an adjacency list (or something similar), so you can find a node's neighbors (reachable via one tuple) in constant time.

Comment: Thank you so much, Trincot! What would you recommend in this situation? Imagine that (A, B) has a cost of 0.8, while (B, C) has a cost of 0.6, and (B, D) has a cost of 0.7, Both (C, A) and (D, A) have equal cost. Our goal is to find the lowest cost, which would be 0.8 + 0.6 + equal_cost < 0.8 + 0.7 + equal_cost. The important thing here is that we don't stop finding "A to A", but rather on "maximum length" of the sequence, such as 6. And out of all sequences that have length of 6, we need to find the one with the minimum cost. Thank you!

Comment: Usually [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) is used for such a scenario. In this case you would not extend paths when they are longer than 6, and you would not stop when finding the target node with shorter length. But when you find it with a length of 6, you'll be sure to have the path with minimal cost. See also [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).